# Offering file download within a session

Tags: php

I am trying to make a file download dependent inside a session. Here is the code:

```
<?php>
    session_name("My-Download");

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['Download-Authorized'] = 1;

    echo "<a class='invlink' rel='nofollow' download target='_blank' href='download.php?download_file=file.to.download.pdf'>Name of File</a><br /><br />";

?>
```

The download script ('download.php') comes next:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['Download-Authorized'])) {
        exit;
    }
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/downdir/"; 
    $fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];

    if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);

        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
            print($buffer);
            flush();
        }
        fclose ($fd);
    } else {
        die("File does not exist. Make sure you specified correct file name.");
    }
    exit;
?>
```

All works fine as long as the verification of '$_SESSION['Download-Authorized'] ist commented out. 
When I check the session-variable $_SESSION['Download-Authorized'] is set
the download will fail.

What's wrong with my code?

Any help appreciated.

After adding session_start() to the beginning of download.php the script still does not work.
It appears to be the case that the Session-ID as well as the Session-Name changes when  "download.php" is called. Additionally $_SESSION['Downlad-Autorized'] is reset.

Comment: `download.php` needs `session_start()` at the beginning.

Comment: have you used <?php session_start(); ?>

Comment: adding <?php session_start(); ?> at the beginning of download.php doesn't change the failure of the download-script.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial script stores the flag in a session explicitely renamed (`session_name("My-Download");`), but the download script uses the default session name (no `session_name()`).

Therefore your download script starts with another (possibly empty) session.